# What motivates the study of Abelian groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, motivation

Monoids arise naturally as endomorphism monoids, and groups arise naturally as automorphism groups. These are among the primary motivators for their study, in my opinion.

What are the (main) motivators of the study of Abelian groups?

Comment: I'd say $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ is a quite natural abelian group. Or $(\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}, \cdot)$.

Comment: @fqp: The question is not about natural examples, but rather why one should care about these. You don't have to know general group theory in order to understand the integers, for instance.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, the original phrasing made it sound more like I was interested in natural examples, hence fgp's comment.

Comment: I groups *arise* as automorphism groups, then what are they automorphisms on?

Comment: @Jack: Objects of arbitrary categories.

Comment: @Martin: You mean arbitrary structured sets. :-)

Comment: @Asaf: ;-) .... nice joke

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the original motivations was number theory, in particular the study of the [ideal class group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_class_group) of a number ring and the group of units $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ notably by C. F. Gauss. More generally, abelian groups arise naturally in terms of [cohomology theories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohomology_theory), which serve to distinguish (geometric) objects by algebraic invariants (refining [Betti numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betti_number)). Kronecker was probably the first one who abstracted from number-theoretic examples and formulated the general axioms of a finite abelian group in his 1870 work *[Auseinandersetzung einiger Eigenschaften der Klassenzahl idealer complexer Zahlen](https://archive.org/stream/leopoldkronecke00berlgoog#page/n293/)*. He also essentially proves the [classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_finitely_generated_abelian_groups) of finite abelian groups. Historically, Camille Jordan coined the terminology of *abelian groups* because Niels Abel had proven that (in modern language) a polynomial with a commutative Galois group is solvable.